# NullInjectorError: No provider for NgZone when referencing a custom npm package

Tags: angular, ngzone

I recently followed this guide to learn how to create an angular library and publish it for my own use: https://medium.com/@nikolasleblanc/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e

After packing the library and referencing it from my own angular project, I came up with this error: NullInjectorError: No provider for NgZone.

When I try to inject NgZone in my controller, without referencing the component in my library which is also injecting it, my project works just fine. However, when I try to reference the library component in my view, it no longer works!

I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out, however there's little to no information regarding this error, and I believe it has nothing to do with NgZone but rather something i overlooked.

I'm not sure what kind of information i should provide to better troubleshoot this error, so please feel free to ask me.

Both my library and project reference Angular 5.0.0 and zone.js 0.8.12. You can find my library published on github under: https://github.com/lakylekidd/skating-library

Any help would be appreciate it, it is driving me crazy!!

Thank you in advance,
Billy

Comment: Did you add `peerDependencies` such as `@angular/core` to `package.json` of your library?

Comment: I did... i have this included `"peerDependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },` but i keep getting the same error.

Comment: Did you publish your library on npm? Can I install it?

Comment: Hello again, yes, i have published my library on npm and tested it out myself... it turns out that it works when I `npm install` as I also did some modifications which I will explain in a post. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out why it wasn't working.

Turns out my library had a dependency for angular 5.2 and my application had angular 5.0, so I upgraded my application to 5.2. Also, as suggested by yurzui, I added peerDependencies with all the libraries I am using. I published my library on npm and `npm install` ed it on my project. It works just fine.

I am not 100% sure what the issue was, but after following all these steps, the issue was gone.

Hope this helps should anyone bump into the same issue in the future.

Billy

Answer (score 0):

Spent a lot of time on this issue:( Hope it will help somebody to save time:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8117

Answer (score -1):

If you are using webpack in your project, it can be solved very easily. 
You can specify the absolute path to your current node_modules when resolving modules.

```
 resolve: {
            extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
            modules: [helpers.root('src'),  helpers.root('node_modules')]
        },
```

By Default webpack is using relative path to node_module, this will cause npm linked packages using their own libs 
specified in their own node_modules

Comment: Don't do this! It can prevent modules with private dependencies from importing the correct version (or any version).